# With a chrome extension, how do I pass a message from background script to content script using a long-lived connection (port)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here is my background script. I am able to send a message to it from my popup script. In other words, the console logs "hello" in the background page.

```
// background.js

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){

    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

        if (msg.greeting == "hello") {

            var port = chrome.tabs.connect(0, {name: "mycontentscript"});

            port.postMessage({greeting:"hello"});

            console.log('hello');
        }
    });
});
```

However, I cannot get the message from the background script to my content script. Here is my content script. The alert is not showing.

```
// content.js

var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name:"mycontentscript"});

port.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender){

    if (message.greeting == "hello") {

        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you forgot establishing the connection, just `postMessage` in content script after the port is created, and reuse the port in `runtime.onConnect.addListener()` in background page.

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.greeting == "hello") {
            port.postMessage({ greeting: "hello" });
            console.log('hello');
        }
    });
});
```

content.js

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "mycontentscript" });
port.postMessage({greeting: "hello"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    if (message.greeting == "hello") {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my situation is exactly like yours, but I also wrote a Chrome extension in which the background page sends a message to the client.

In my [content script](https://github.com/arthurakay/StackOverflow-Notifications/blob/master/ui/jsx/MessageList.js), I do the following:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('requestData', this.updateData.bind(this));
```

In my [background script](https://github.com/arthurakay/StackOverflow-Notifications/blob/master/background/background.js), I have:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({
        messages : inboxMessages,
        userId   : user_id
    });
});
```

And then my content script receives the message:

```
this.updateData = function(data) {
    //...
}
```

Hopefully that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

In the background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){//here you've got the port

    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

        if (msg.greeting == "hello") {
//and here you're making a new, unneeded port, for which nobody is listening. 
//Use the one you've got.
            var port = chrome.tabs.connect(0, {name: "mycontentscript"});

            port.postMessage({greeting:"hello"});

            console.log('hello');
        }
    });
});
```

Either initiate the connect from background with chrome.tabs.connect, and put chrome.runtime.onConnect listener in the tab's content.js, or initiate the connect from the tab, as you did, and use the port obtained in the background's onConnect listener. Just delete that

`var port=chrome.tabs.connect(0, {name: "mycontentscript});`

line.